# traits and abstract types

Tags: scala

Assume I have a base class

```
abstract class Base {

  type B<: Base

  def rep:String

  def copy:B
}

class MyBase(override val rep:String) extends Base {
  type B = MyBase

 override def copy = new MyBase(rep)
}
```

I then try to add another trait as a mixin, for which I want the return type for copy to be the the appropriate type (meaning that calling copy on the mixin returns a mixin type, by setting B to the appropriate type). I haven't been able to get this to compile, or even to understand where the override keyword should go.

Edited: I have refined the example

```
abstract class Base {


  type B <: Base

  def rep:String

  def copy:B

}

class MyBase(val rep:String) extends Base {

  type B = MyBase

  def copy = new MyBase(rep)
}


trait DecBase extends Base {

  abstract override def rep = "Rep: "+super.rep   
}
```

My question is, how do I declare an appropriate type B and copy method for DecBase, so that the copy returns a DecBase , and also, why won't this compile?

```
println(((new MyBase("ofer") with DecBase)).rep)
```

This is something I would have achieved in Java (with some nastiness, using recursive generic types). I'm sure that it's possible to do something nicer in Scala.

**Edit**

Using

```
trait DecBase extends Base {

  override type B = DecBase
  abstract override  val rep= "Dec:"+super.rep
  abstract override def copy = new MyBase(rep) with DecBase
}
```

I get the following compiler errors

```
error: overriding type B in class MyBase, which equals com.amadesa.scripts.MyBase;
type B in trait DecBase, which equals com.amadesa.scripts.DecBase has incompatible type
println(((new MyBase("ofer") with DecBase)).rep)

error: overriding type B in class MyBase, which equals com.amadesa.scripts.MyBase;
type B in trait DecBase, which equals com.amadesa.scripts.DecBase has incompatible type
abstract override def copy = new MyBase(rep) with DecBase
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume your mix in looks something like this

```
trait MixIn extends Base {
  override B = MixinBase
  override def copy = new MixinBase(rep)
}
```

I think the `override` on `MyBase` is part of the problem. It's unnecessary and confuses the compiler.

If the `copy` on `Base` in fact has an implementation, making `override` necessary, you need to tell the compiler which method to use. If it's not obvious to it, it throws up its hands and raises an error. Try this.

```
val b = new MyBase(rep) with MixIn {
  override def copy = MixIn.super.copy
}
```

The `MixIn.super.copy` is a call to the one you want.

You may want to review this page on [Scala Class Linearization](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/08/scala-class-linearization.html) to understand what happens when you have competing implementations of a method in a type.

Edit: oh this is a completely different problem. It's the val in `case MyBase(val rep:String)`. You can't override a val with a def because a val is assumed to be immutable. You can override a def or var with a val, but not the other way around. Make it:

```
trait DecBase extends Base {
  abstract override val rep = "Rep: "+super.rep
}
```

Please include the compiler error next time. It makes it so much easier to see what the problem is.

Comment: Edited again, added compiler errors this time. The important thing for me is the correct return type for the copy method.

Comment: Now I'm having trouble making it work. To start with, you can't override B to be DecBase because DecBase isn't a subtype of MyBase. But after fixing that, I'm still getting an error. The compiler doesn't seem to like overriding type B = MyBase, but it maybe something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's somehow connected to `val rep` in class `MyBase`. You should define `MyBase` abstract, if you are not going to implement `def rep`.

Here is working example:

```
abstract class Base {
  type B <: Base
  def rep:String
  def copy: B
}

class MyBase(val repVal: String) extends Base {
  type B = MyBase
  def rep = repVal
  def copy = new MyBase(repVal)
}


trait DecBase extends Base {
  abstract override def rep = "Rep: " + super.rep
}

println(((new MyBase("ofer"))).rep) // prints: ofer
println(((new MyBase("ofer") with DecBase)).rep) // prints: Rep: ofer
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. In Scala, having a def or val are interchangeable. the val rep thing is an implementation of rep.

Comment: Sorry, seems that I forgot something fundamental :) Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it, the goal is to be able to do:

```
val myBase: MyBase = new MyBase("alone")
val myBaseCopy: MyBase = myBase.copy

val decBase: DecBase = new MyBase("mixed") with DecBase
val decBaseCopy: DecBase = decBase.copy
```

Lets rewrite your code to use type bounds instead of equality in your `type` declarations (and also to fix the mismatch between `val rep` and `def rep` which is hiding some other compiler errors):

```
abstract class Base {
  type B <: Base
  def rep: String
  def copy: B
}

class MyBase(_rep: String) extends Base {
  type B <: MyBase
  def rep = _rep
  def copy = new MyBase(rep)
}

trait DecBase extends Base {
  override type B <: DecBase
  override abstract def rep = "Rep: " + super.rep   
}
```

This now says that `MyBase.copy` should return a `MyBase` or a subclass, and `DecBase.copy` should return a `DecBase` or a subclass. I believe that's what you want, right? Now the resulting compiler error is clear:

```
temp.scala:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.MyBase
 required: MyBase.this.B
  def copy = new MyBase(rep)
             ^
one error found
```

So you're returning a `MyBase` but you really need to be returning the subclass, e.g. you want to be returning `new MyBase(rep) with DecBase` instead of `new MyBase(rep)`, but only when your object was declared as `new MyBase(...) with DecBase`. I don't know any way to do that, though perhaps you might look at [adding a trait after an object has been constructed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893274/scala-and-traits-on-object-instances).

Comment: Does not compile, even if I restrict to Base and MyBase, and forget DecBase. Compiler complains: error: type mismatch;
found   : com.amadesa.scripts.MyBase
required: MyBase.this.B
def copy = new MyBase(rep)

Comment: Exactly. You want your `DecBase.copy` to return a `DecBase` but that's not possible because `MyBase` is actually creating the object and `MyBase` knows nothing about `DecBase`. You're expecting `DecBase` to somehow change the line `new MyBase(rep)` to `new MyBase(rep) with DecBase`.