# Is it possible to mix in a trait to an already existing object?

Tags: scala, traits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [scala and traits on object instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893274/scala-and-traits-on-object-instances)

Is it possible to mix in a trait to an already existing object ?

Something like:

```
val s = new MyClass
val sWithTrait = s with myTrait
```

The code above does not work, but maybe the syntax is wrong or it is not possible at all ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893274/scala-and-traits-on-object-instances ... hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic mixins are not possible in regular Scala, but I seem to remember that there was an attempt at a compiler plugin called [Autoproxy](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=275588) that allowed something along these lines. Not sure about the state of it though.