# "Intersection types" in Scala

Tags: scala, types, intersection

I know that "union types" are not supported in Scala, but what about intersection types?

In short, I would like a function like this:

```
def intersect[A,B,C](a: A, b: B): C = ??? // a & b
```

Or a method :

```
class A {
    def intersect[B, C](b: B): C = ??? // this & b
}
```

`A` and `B` share a common superclass ensuring the validity of the intersect operation, and `C` would be a type at the intersection of`A` or `B`.

In my use case, A or B represent either variables or constants (of the same type). I want to distinguish, class-wise, a constant from a variable with singleton domain. If I try to intersect a set with a value, I return the value (or return the empty set/throw an exception if the value is not in the set).

Here is an example of expected output:

```
trait IntExpression {
  // Correct signature to be determined
  def intersect [A <: IntExpression, B <: A & this.type] (that: A): B
}
case class IntVariable(domain: Seq[Int]) extends IntExpression
case class IntConstant(value: Int) extends IntExpression

val a = IntVariable(1,2,3)
val b = IntVariable(2,3,4)
val c = IntConstant(2)
```

And then:

```
a intersect b == b intersect a == IntVariable(2,3)
a intersect c == c intersect a == IntConstant(2)
```

Comment: May be you can write a macro that derives such set? As long as it has access to the class hierarchy, it should be possible.

Comment: I don't quite understand what output you expect. Could you maybe give an example for the possible input values and the expected output?

Comment: I don't see the use-case for this. Why don't you just use sets?

Comment: I want to implement a DSL for a constraint programming solver. I am referring to an existing external DSL which distinguishes variables from constants. There even exists a third type of expression which represents a sequence of expressions (and is hard to unify with the remaining of the type system :()

This distinction is often useful because it can lead to interesting optimizations. They could also be triggered by checking the domain size, but I wanted to use pattern-matching and additional type safety to my system.

Comment: If you want to specify that a type is a subtype of both `A` and `B` write `A with B`.

Comment: What happens if there's no intersection between the sets?

Comment: There is actually a way to encode union types in Scala. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/does-scala-have-type-disjunction-union-types).

Answer (score 2):

As ziggystar is correctly stated above: `A & B` is `A with B` in Scala.

Regarding the fact you want to create your adjoint types `C` in runtime, you must want to create this type in runtime, based on the types you got in `A` and `B`.

Solution for this, or at least a clue, you may find at [How to mix-in a trait to instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893274/scala-and-traits-on-object-instances).

However, what you want at your use-case is a case of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type. In spite of the fact that dependent types are not supported in Scala, you may always try Agda ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use `++` as implementation because it's there. And `intersect` on `Set` doesn't work because `Set` is invariant. If this doesn't make sense, ignore it.

```
def intersect[C, A <: C, B <: C](as: Seq[A], bs: Seq[B]): Seq[C] = as ++ bs
```

Comment: This is wrong.  `intersect(Seq(1,2,3), Seq(2,3,4)) == Seq(1,2,3,2,3,4)`  The op is looking for a result of `Seq(2,3)`